# The element ID use snake case dont work with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<form name="my_form" autocomplete="off" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  Email: <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" required>
  <tt>myForm = {{my_form}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

The result is

> myForm = {"input":{}}

But when I replaced the ID "my_form" whith "my-form", the result changed to be

> myForm = 0

Dose it means that the snake case name is conflict with angularjs? Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the bit inside `{{}}` can be an Angular expression, and in this case Angular is assuming you're trying to perform a mathematical operation.

Thus, if you subtract `form` from `my`, the result is `0`.

Comment: Thanks.But how can I make it work to use snake case in Angularjs.

Comment: Using `my_form` works fine, so you can already use snake case.  You cannot use hyphens in JavaScript variable names, however, so `my-form` will never work, but hyphens aren't considered snake case anyway.